# Problems with my Dlookup and Dmax

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to solve a problem in Access-2010. A Student number consists of 1314 followed by a 4 digit number.
The 4 digit number is sequential i.e. each one is 1 higher than the last.  So, if the last Student number in use was `13140925` then the next should be `13140926`.

The formula at present looks like this:

```
=1314&DMax(“Right(StudentNumber,4)”,“TBLStudent”)+1
```

However, this generates an error. I've also tried this:

```
=DLookUp(“Left(StudentNumber,4)”,“TBLStudent”&DMAX(Right(“StudentNumber,4)”,“TBLStudent”)+1)
```

Which I prefer as the 1st 4 digits can be anything and not just 1314. Anyhow, can someone please help me to identify the mistakes?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Make a Query or something else? What error do you receive?

Comment: You are doing something wrong, the two data should be in their seperate column, combined together forming a composite Primary Key. The current setup of having them in one column is your problem.

Comment: @Wouter Sry trying to make a form. I've added an unbound text box and I'm trying to add the formula into that .

Comment: @PailFrancis - possibly, but I don't really want to edit the design of the table, the formula should work - grrr...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
=Left(DLookUp("StudentNumber","TBLStudent"), 4) & Right(Val(DMax("StudentNumber","TBLStudent")) + 1, 4)
```

Comment: right - many thanks. So am I right in thinking that the function Val is essentially setting the value of the unbound box

Comment: No, it forces a numeric from what could be a string returned from DMax. This allows 1 to be added.